# How do I apply the inverse cube law for magnetic flux density/distance of a solenoid after finding $B$ from the formula $B=\mu ni$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

The title says it all. I want to use $B/B^{*}=(D^{\ast})^{3}/D^3$ to calculate the flux density over distance straight, measured out from the core of a simple solenoid. If I calculate $B$ for the solenoid using $B=\mu ni$, where in space is the flux density at that value? And at what distance from where?

This is probably a really simple problem, but without an initial distance value $D$ for $B$, I don't know how to find $B^{*}$. Is $D$ related to the dimensions of the solenoid somehow? Thanks!